# Inserting dynamic variables into an HTML template...PHP? ASP? ColdFusion? MySQL?

Tags: php, asp.net, mysql, html, variables

I have looked on this site, googled, and even searched adobe developer central, without luck. As such, I think I might not know the correct terminology to search for, as my question is pretty straight-forward. Thus, if the title was misleading I apologize.

I'd like to learn how to create an HTML template which will then insert variables as needed, specifically, the names of cities and states (for a franchise), where it is appropriate.

[Self-edited after realizing my initial post was way too broad]

How to do this, or perhaps more importantly the terminology I should use in queries so I find relevant information, would be awesome...

On a related note, are all the dynamic scripting languages compatible with all the database technologies (the only book I read on it dealt with PHP and MySQL)?

Thanks everybody.

Comment: I recommend scouring Amazon.com for some basic beginner's books that are well-reviewed, and buy them or check them out somewhere. SO is not either a recommendation or tutorial discussion site.

Comment: I realized that before seeing your comment. Sorry...I think I revised it to be specific enough to be pertinent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "new hotness" in the interwebs is client-side templating (eg in the browser via JavaScript), *&* either have your data in the HTML or JavaScript & hiddent/unhidden as needed, *OR* use AJAX/JSON/XML to get new data from the server dynamically.

Linkedin switched to client-side templating: http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/client-side-templating-throwdown-mustache-handlebars-dustjs-and-more

Comment: BTW:
_then insert variables as needed, specifically, the names of cities and states (for a franchise),_
is not a "variable"; city/state pairs is data, & you would use a variable or 2 to pick out what subset of data you want.  You MAY call the "variable" 'cityState' or 'cityName' or 'fetched_city' or 'gofish' if you want ;)